# Replace Existing Vimeo API is not working in POSTMAN

Tags: postman, vimeo-api

I am trying to hit this API,  Replace the existing video in Vimeo but my curl is not working.

curl --location --request PUT 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/813466834/replace' 
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'access-control-allow-credentials: true' 
--header 'content-type: text/plain' 
--header 'Cookie: vuid=1926240844.568182782' 
--form '=@"/C:/Users/PMR/Downloads/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4"'

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this documentation for versioning and replacing a video: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#create_video_version. Please remove the token for security concerns.

Comment: Yeah I have tried this earlier also, It's not working . Tried with different combination . Still it doesn't work. I have gone through documentation there I have not found proper method to replace .

Comment: Please create a ticket with support and our team can take a deeper look. Thanks